# Adding a radio group to a custom Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button

I am trying to dynamic radio buttons to a custom dialog but not able to get it added in my custom dialog

```
 final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
 RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); 
 rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

        // layout params to use when adding each radio button
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

 // add 5 radio buttons to the group

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
      String label = "item set" + i;
      rb[i].setText(label);
      rb[i].setId(i);
      rg.addView(rb[i],layoutParams);

      }
 ll2.addView(rg);

--------------------------------------------------------------------

 Context context=LocationActivity.this;
 dialog=new Dialog(context);
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------

 Linearlayout2 is defined in custom_dialog.xml file. I must be doing something wrong but not able to figure it out. Other widgets are getting displayed except radiogroup buttons.
```

Any pointer to this issue is appreicated.

Thanks!
Swz

custom_dialog file as below:

It has 2 textview widgets and a radiogroup declared. I am able to add the same layout successfully to an activity screen but not to custom dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linlayoutBase"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="Longitute: "
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="unknown"
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearMain"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
          android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add the `R.layout.custom_dialog` file?

Comment: Are you getting an error or are they just not appearing? Also, I see you're saying `Linearlayout2` is in the `custom_dialog` layout but you call id `linearDialog`

Comment: There is no LinearLayout with the id `@+id/linearDialog` in that XML... Are you getting a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Sorry typo mistake, the LinearLayout ll2 is linearMain. No, the radiobuttons are just not getting displayed on the customdialog.

Comment: I get null pointerexception if I try to declare the radiogroup as RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);

Comment: Drop this line: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from your `RadioGroup` in xml, don't think that will help but you don't need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the XML you posted, try this:

```
Context context=LocationActivity.this;
dialog=new Dialog(context);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

View view = LayoutInflater.fromContext(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null, false);
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
RadioGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 // add 5 radio buttons to the group
RadioButton rb;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    rb = new RadioButton(context);
    rb.setText("item set" + i);
    rb.setId(i);
    rg.addView(rb, layoutParams);
}

dialog.setContentView(view);
```

I didn't see how you were changing your Dialog layout. So I inflated the layout, added the RadioButtons, and then passed the completed layout to `dialog`.

Also, because the `linearMain` only has one child you can remove this LinearLayout and simply use `radioGroup`.

Comment: You may want to search for the `RadioGroup` on the *view* to actually find it.

Comment: Yes, I need not have to create a second RadioGroup in the layout but for some reasons the first one was giving null pointer exception. I tried this solution but is not working for me. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, I am not getting the exception now, but the dialog just displays the first two text widgets.

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks, always helps to have an extra set of eyes.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. was struggling with this for last 2 hours.